# sencha touch :: Problems with disable()/enable()of a FormPanel

Tags: forms, sencha-touch

thats weired - it worked and suddenly (changed nothing but adding code to other panels...) it's not working any more:

I used to enable/disable a form with a button inside a docked toolbar. within the handler ofthe button the disable/enable is triggered with a simple

```
formBase.enable();
```

but this is throwing the error

> *TypeError: Result of expression 'formBase.enable' [undefined] is not a
>   function.*

now.

I don't get it....
any help would be great!
thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probabilly have a scope issue, so you can't get your formBase variable from the button handler.
I post you a full working example I've done to let you understand how it is possible to enable / disable your form.

```
Ext.setup({
onReady: function() {

    var form = new Ext.form.FormPanel({
        scroll: 'vertical',
        fullscreen: true,
        url   : 'postUser.php',
        standardSubmit : false,
        dockedItems: [{
            xtype: 'toolbar',
            title: 'Example',
            items: [{
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'Disable',
                handler: function(){
                    form.disable();
                }
            },{
                xtype: 'spacer'
            },{
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'Enable',
                handler: function(){
                    form.enable();
                }
            }]
        }],
        items: [{
            xtype: 'fieldset',
            title: 'Personal Info',
            instructions: 'Please enter the information above.',
            defaults: {
                required: true,
                labelAlign: 'left',
                labelWidth: '40%'
            },
            items: [
            {
                xtype: 'textfield',
                name : 'name',
                label: 'Name',
                useClearIcon: true,
                autoCapitalize : false
            }, {
                xtype: 'passwordfield',
                name : 'password',
                label: 'Password',
                useClearIcon: false
            }]
        }]
    });

    form.show();
}
});
```

Hope This helps.